# How to average a set of images and save the averaged image as the averaged image using MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have 5 digital holograms that I recorded using a CCD at different times. I would like to average the 5.

I am able to do that by the following code in MATLAB, except that I am unable to save the file as I see in MATLAB. Instead I get a white image after saving.

```
I0 = imread('snap1.bmp');
sumImage = double(I0); % Inialize to first image.
for i=2:10 % Read in remaining images.
  rgbImage = imread(['snap',num2str(i),'.bmp']);
  sumImage = sumImage + double(rgbImage);
end;
meanImage = sumImage / 5;

figure
imshow(meanImage,[])
imwrite(double(meanImage),'snap10.bmp')

o=imread('snap10.bmp');
figure
imagesc((o))
```

[images can be found at](https://www.jumbomail.me/he/Downloads.aspx?sid=56576F6875567969785676464B3342347436653838673D3D)

Comment: https://www.jumbomail.me/he/Downloads.aspx?sid=56576F6875567969785676464B3342347436653838673D3D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you transform the image into the `uint8`, it would be correct:

```
imwrite(uint8(meanImage),'snap10.bmp'); % instead of double
```

Also, the mean is wrong as you sum `1:10`, but divided the sum by `5`.

Comment: I tried that but it shows error 
Undefined function 'unit8' for input arguments of type
'double'.

Comment: @sanjeev yes. you misstyped `uint8`.

Comment: Omg!! Thank you :)